# Finding the First Turning Point of a function in C

Tags: c, eclipse, while-loop, calculus

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    setvbuf(stderr,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    double x, y;        
    double a=0.4+(6019.0/25000.0);          
    double diff;
    double diff2;

    x=0;          //Starting Value of x=0
    diff=a;     //Setting diff to start with value of 'a'. Because at x=0, f'(x)=a


    while(fabs(diff)>0)     //Starts a while loop, which runs until diff<=0
    {
        diff=(a*pow(x, a-1)-((1/a)*pow(x, (1/a)-1)+a)) * cos(pow(x, a) - pow(x, 1/a) + (a*x));      //f'(x)
        x+=0.0001;      

    }

printf(" The First Maximum Turning Point is at x=%g\n",x);      //prints the x coordinate of the TP

return 0;
}
```

I am trying to find the first turning point of a function using the a linear search method in C.

You can ignore my 'y' variable as this is related to an earlier part of the code which is irrelevant.

I am trying to use a while loop to put x into dy/dx (i have verified that the derivative is correct), and while |dy/dx| > 0 (aka while it is not a turning point), x is increased slightly each time until dy/dx hits zero. It is then meant to print the value of x at this point.

However when I run this code, all I get is a never-ending loop.

And if i use `while(diff>0)`instead, I get a value of x which is nowhere near the correct value.

I am really lost here and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely that `fabs(diff)` will equate to exactly zero; maybe you should compare it to some very small number instead.

Comment: `while(fabs(diff)>0) ` change to `while(fabs(diff)>eps) ` where `eps` is defined as a small number depending on your error tolerances. Like maybe `1.0e-4`.

Comment: `while(fabs(diff)>0)` says one thing but your comment next to `while` loop says otherwise.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I changed the zero to 1e-5 and it is giving me the same (incorrect) output as i was getting for when I used 'while(diff>0)'

Comment: @Aspect Try comparing to a value that's twice the step size of `x`; e.g. if step size is 0.0001, try `while(fabs(diff)>0.0002)`.

Comment: Instead of checking whether `diff` hits zero more or less exactly, you could try to find the point where it changes its sign, i.e. where it goes from positive to negative. By the way, your first evaluation at `x == 0.0` yields negative infinity, because `a - 1` is negative and `pow(0, a - 1)` is a division by zero, so better increment `x` before evaluating.

Comment: Hmm ... I graphed your function and the first zero crossing is at approximately 0.168, which is what your code should be giving you. In general though, you don't want to find roots in this fashion. Look up "numerical root finding algorithms" for better ideas. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you are comparing a double value with zero which is never meet and result is never ending loop.

For example

```
  if(.00001 > 0 )// a true value
```

and

```
  if(.00000000000000000001 > 0 )//is still true.
```

hence your while loop is became never ending loop. Hence try with something like below

```
   while(fabs(diff)> .00001 )
```